# Atom Editor - Body Keybind for Everything Except Vim Mode Insert

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I am an avid Vim user who recently decided to give Atom a try. In vim I map `,bn & ,bp` to next buffer and previous buffer, respectively. I am trying to imitate the same behavior in Atom for switching between tabs. In my keymap.cson file I have the following:

```
'body':
  ', b n': 'pane:show-next-item'
  ', b p': 'pane:show-previous-item'
```

This will work except if I try to type just the ',' character in Vim mode insert it will not display unless I hit ',' twice.

I thought maybe the following would work, but it had no effect:

```
'body .vim-mode:not(.insert-mode)':
  ', b n': 'pane:show-next-item'
  ', b p': 'pane:show-previous-item'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I simply forgot to add the `atom-text-editor` selector before the `.vim-mode:not(.insert-mode)` selector. Changed the script to the following and it worked:

```
'body atom-text-editor.vim-mode:not(.insert-mode)':
  ', b n': 'pane:show-next-item'
  ', b p': 'pane:show-previous-item'
```