# Atom - Adding a keybind shortcut to insert code snippet

Tags: coldfusion, text-editor, atom-editor, key-bindings

I'm trying to create a keybind in the Atom text editor that will insert the code:

```
<cfdump var="##">
```

and

```
<cfabort>
```

using ctrl+shift+d and ctrl+shift+a respectively, just as it is in Eclipse. The [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761199/add-simple-keybinding-in-atom) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360365/atom-editor-body-keybind-for-everything-except-vim-mode-insert) don't touch on this issue.

So far, I've tried editing the keymap.cson file with

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-d': 'custom:insert-dump'

'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-a': 'custom:insert-abort'
```

and adding the below to init.coffee:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
  'custom:insert-dump':   ->
    atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('<cfdump var=\"\#\#\">')

atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
  'custom:insert-abort':   ->
    atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('<cfabort>')
```

I've managed to get the < cfabort > to work, but the cfdump just produces a newline. I'm sure I'm making some silly mistake. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Similar question was asked off-site: https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-replace-a-keymap-binding/16834 - top answer: `You can open the keybinding resolver (ctrl+.) and then press the keybinding to see which scope it is bound to. Then you can unset! that key combo for that specific scope.` TLDR, it's possible you have other bindings that are overriding your CFML stuff.

Comment: Doh! It WAS already mapped to something. However, altering these keybinds seems to be an open issue. Instead, I've opted to edit the snippets.cson file with the following:

'*':
  'cfabort':
    'prefix': 'ab'
    'body': '<cfabort>'
  'cfdump':
    'prefix': 'd'
    'body': '<cfdump var="#$1#">'

The Kleene star, *, applies it to all files. Now when I type ab and press tab, it autocompletes to <cfabort>. Similarly, 'd' autocompletes to <cfdump var="##"> with the cursor in between the ##.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In keymap.cson, I added:

```
 'atom-text-editor':
   'alt-q': 'custom:tom'
```

In init.coffee, I added:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'custom:tom', ->
  editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
  tomstring  = editor.getSelectedText()
  editor.insertNewlineBelow()
  editor.insertText('<cfdump var="#'+tomstring+'#" label="'+tomstring+'"><cfabort>')
  editor.save()
```

To use in the editor hightlight what you want to dump and do alt-q.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by changing the `keymap.cson` to:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-d': 'custom:insert-dump'
  'ctrl-shift-a': 'custom:insert-abort'
```

and the init.coffee to:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
  'custom:insert-dump':   ->
    atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('<cfdump var=\"\#\#\">')
  'custom:insert-abort':   ->
    atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('<cfabort>')
```